# How to check when UINavigationController is REALLY hidden?

Tags: ios

I want to resize the height of a custom view inside a tableview when the navigation bar is hidden when scrolling.

The problem is `(self.navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden == YES)` is true even though the navigation bar only started animating to hide. Moreover, even though the navigation bar did not hide, (as when user stopped scrolling) `navigationBarHidden == YES` still has TRUE value.

So my question is how can I know when the navigationController is **really** hidden?

(I have tried reading the documentation as well as searching for this question but to no avail. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.)

Comment: Update your question with relevant code showing how you hide the nav bar and check when it is hidden.

Comment: If you're using storyboards and auto layout, constraining the top of your custom view to the top of your table view, and the top of your table view to the Top Layout Guide, then your views will adjust themselves as the navigation bar is shown and hidden.

Comment: @NRitH, your suggestion sounds promising. I will try it out and will let you know if it works. Thanks!